# Broken schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser'

Tags: settings, glib

For the past few weeks (after a distribution upgrade), about every program with a graphical user interfaces crashes at some point with the same error:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' does not contain a key named 'last-folder-uri'
```

It happens every time a file open dialog shows up, but also when the network manager asks for a WiFi password. (Which means I can't open files in any gtk application and only connect to open wireless networks.)

`/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` does contain `<key name='last-folder-uri'`

Running `glib-compile-schemas` doesn't seem to help.

It's not just for one user. If I log in as a guest ('Guest Session'), the same happens.

```
$ dpkg -s libgtk-3-common | grep Version
Version: 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.3
```

Contents of `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml`:

```
<https://gist.github.com/f90a230bf6077cbaa967>
```

Comment: isn't this no-repro now? Did you ever fix it?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but... just for future reference.

I already met this very same issue, just with a different key: you probably have a double `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` file installed on your filesystem.

You should remove that file (I just uninstalled the culprit package) to solve the issue. Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820733/firefox-hangs-because-sort-directories-first-setting-missing) for further details.

Comment: better to flag the question as a duplicate in this case

Comment: @Zanna but I'm not sure this is due to the same cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it manually:

```
 dconf write "/org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/last-folder-uri" "'file:///home/'"
```

Moreover, make sure that `gsettings-data-convert` is in your startup applications.

Comment: When trying to set it manually, it says: ``Schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' is relocatable (path must be specified)``

Comment: Ok, I've edited. Try now!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. ``dconf write ...`` goes fine; the value does now appear in ``dconf-editor``. (Before, ``/opt/gtk/`` didn't even contain ``settings``.) But all programs still give the same error about not finding the ``last-folder-uri`` key.

Comment: After gsettings-data-convert?

Comment: Yes, tried that already. Didn't help.  Dconf and Gsettings save their setting per user, right? (Because if i log in as a guest (guest session), I get the same errors, which i think is strange.)

Comment: Ok, now please post `dpkg -s libgtk-3-common | grep -i version` and your complete `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml`

Comment: Done, see 'Edit 2' in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling gtk+3 via package manager fixed the problem. Previously, the mentioned scheme was missing. (I cannot comment.)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. You can set `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` to control which scheme has preference.

See [this from GNOME mail](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2011-February/msg00113.html).