# Firefox hangs because sort-directories-first setting missing

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, firefox, gsettings

I recently upgraded from xubuntu 14.04 to xubuntu 16.04. The process finished but did not go smooth (I don't remember why).

Now in `firefox` when I open a file (*File* -> *Open File*) the process crashes with the following error:

```
... GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' does not contain a key named 'sort-directories-first'
```

I searched around the web and did not find anything relevant. Reinstalling `firefox`, `gsettings-desktop-schemas` and `gsettings-ubuntu-schemas` (with `apt-get install --reinstall ...`) did not change anything. I also tried rebuilding the schemas but the error is always the same:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

The (not so) funny thing is that the key exists!

```
grep sort-directories-first /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/*
Binary file /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled matches
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml:    <key type="b" name="sort-directories-first">
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml:    <key type="b" name="sort-directories-first">
```

At the end I tried manually creating the key. With `gsettings` it complains the key does not exist:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-directories-first false
Not such key 'sort-directories-first'
```

With `dconf` I can create that key but nothing changes:

```
dconf write /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/sort-directories-first false
```

Comment: 1. What are the override files you have in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`? 2. What is the full output of `grep sort-directories-first /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/*`? is it what you said in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` exists and contains the desired key `sort-directories-first`.

We know from the answer by WinEunuuchs2Unix that the system will look for the file in a location depending on the value of `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable.

So what happen when the system looks for `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` in a different location ?

The error-message doesn't tell us that the system can't find the file, the message tells us that the system can't find the key in the file. That makes me sure that you have a second file named `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` somewhere in your system and this file doesn't contain the desired key.

As a workaround I would suggest that you search for files with the name `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml`, I am sure you will find more than only one. Check the content of that file in the different location if it contains the desired key, it will not.

Copy over from

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schema/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml
```

You may check the value of `XDG_DATA_DIRS` with `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS` in terminal, that may give you a clue where to search for files.

I couldn't find out how to set the value for `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, the value will be set during start-up by a bash-script, but information I found seemed to be outdated.

Your issue might be related with [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1613970) bug, Google leads me to this link while searching the net about your issue.

Comment: OP already said they have `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml`

Comment: @Anwar yes, this file exits in a specific location,and it doesn't seem to be the file accessed by the system, otherwise the system would have found the key.
The location were the system looks up for the file are defined in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`.
If `XDG_DATA_DIRS` contains wrong value the system will look up for the file in a different location and might find a file with the same name there but this file doesn't contain the key. This really could be the case here and is worth to be checked.

Comment: OP created the key in the file. Now the system should find the key right? And I found that, Xubuntu (and Ubuntu) doesn't store .gschema files elsewhere.

Comment: Really good catch. I compiled a custom GLib library some time ago and that library installed a `/usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` schema. Uninstalling that library resolved the issue. In fact `/usr/local/share` precedes `/usr/share` on my `XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

Comment: congrats! Indeed a good one

Answer (score 2):

Just a little background:

**glib-compile-schemas** compiles all the GSettings XML schema files in `DIRECTORY` into a binary file with the name `gschemas.compiled` that can be used by GSettings. The XML schema files must have the filename extension `.gschema.xml`. For a detailed description of the XML file format, see the GSettings documentation.

At runtime, GSettings looks for schemas in the `glib-2.0/schemas` subdirectories of all directories specified in the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable. The usual location to install schema files is `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`.

In addition to schema files, glib-compile-schemas reads 'vendor override' files, which are key files that can override default values for keys in the schemas. The group names in the key files are the schema id, and the values are written in serialized GVariant form. Vendor override files must have the filename extension `.gschema.override`.

By convention, vendor override files begin with `nn_` where `nn` is a number from 00 to 99. Higher numbered files have higher priority (eg: if the same override is made in a file numbered 10 and then again in a file numbered 20, the override from 20 will take precedence).

If I'm reading your setup correctly you have your `.xml` files in:

```
/usr/share/glib/schemas
```

and not in:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

where they are expected to be.

If I read it wrong please let me know and I'll delete this answer.  I don't use FireFox so could not test the answer like I usually to do.

Comment: Sorry, the grep output was slightly wrong... I just updated the answer (it was not copy&paste). The /usr/share/glib/ directory doesn't even exist.