# How to fix "GLib-GIO-ERROR Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' is not installed"?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gtk

After updating my ubuntu 20.04 installation first inkscape "Save as" led to a crash of the program complaining about the FileChooser. While trying to fix the problem, now also `nautilus .` gives the same error:

org.gnome.Nautilus:5098): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 21:48:41.547: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' is not installed

Failed attempts to fix the issue:

1. Reinstalling gtk3 `sudo apt-get reinstall gtk-3.0` followed by logout/login.
2. Installing gtk2 via `sudo apt-get install gtk2.0` followed by logout/login.

Possibly related: [broken-schema-org-gtk-settings-filechooser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164570/broken-schema-org-gtk-settings-filechooser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This schema is contained in `libgtk-3-common` package. You have to reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk-3-common
```

Comment: Didn't help for trying to work with Inkscape 1.1 (snap) on Kubuntu 20.04, `libgtk-3-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 3.24.20-0ubuntu1`

Comment: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2495 `sudo snap remove inkscape && sudo snap install inkscape`

Comment: Why do you think that your problem is the same? Please ask new question then.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mess up the schema for any reason and you are no longer able to open the Gnome settings, e.g. gnome-control-center, just do the following and then logout and back in (or simply reboot):

```
rm .config/dconf/user
```

That’s it! Enjoy!

Sources:

- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/how-to-reset-gnome-desktop-settings-to.html
- https://techienotes.blog/2021/10/11/how-to-get-rid-of-glib-gio-error-settings-schema-does-not-contain-a-key-on-gnome-40/